# Deploying PredictionIO with AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, predictionio

I've just followed the example process as described in the [predictionio docs](https://docs.prediction.io/system/deploy-cloudformation/) to create a PredictionIO Cluster on AWS CloudFormation but my stack rolled back right after creation.

Did any of you successfully follow the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked through the error logs and found the self explaining error message:

> Value (us-east-1a) for parameter availabilityZone is invalid. Subnets can currently only be created in the following availability zones: us-west-2b, us-west-2a, us-west-2c.